# Need to split up packets and rebuild again at destination

Tags: tcpip, hosting, terminal-services

Cant go into too much details here for various reasons but here's what I've got.

I've a host which replies to a terminal with a receipt containing info of what items have been purchased at the terminal.

However the network carrier we are using can only carry packets < 1024 bytes -  because that's the way its built and they are not changing it.

Is there any simple way / software that I can use to split a message of say 3000 bytes into smaller packets so it can pass through the carrier network and be rebuilt as one at the terminal side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called fragmentation, and IP does this automatically. For best results, make sure all firewalls or router ACLs between your servers and your terminals allow ICMP "Destination Unreachable, Fragmentation Required but 'Don't Fragment' bit set" messages to pass unmolested.

Or you could probably statically configure your terminals and servers with a path MTU of 1024.

By the way, you won't be able to do IPv6 over that carrier's network, since IPv6 requires a minimum MTU of 1280 bytes.